# Avoiding mutiple refs to props in component

Tags: reactjs, redux

A typical component is like this where I duplicate my props, Is there a best practice to get props just once for the component? Rather than set them again in the `submitForm()`

```
class Screen3 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  submitForm(e) {

    const age = this.props.age;
    const gender = this.props.gender;
    const ethnicity = this.props.ethnicity;

    ....
  }

  onChange(e) {
    const field = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;

    ...
  }

  render() {
    let { age, gender, ethnicity } = this.props;

   ....


const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return {
    age: store.UserDetails.age,
    gender: store.UserDetails.gender,
    ethnicity: store.UserDetails.ethnicity

  };
};
```

Comment: You would probably want to get the props fresh rather than once, as they may have changed later after you get their value . You can use Object destructuring in submitForm `const { age, gender, ethnicity } = this.props;` rather than getting each value

Comment: What do you mean by "just once"? You get properties whenever you need them. BTW you could use destructuring in `mapStateToProps` and `submitForm` the way you did inside `render`.

Comment: store them in local state inside `componentDidMount`. But you might need to update them again if props are changed inside `componentWillRecieveProps`

Comment: there is nohting wrong with getting the props multipletimes.